Does Hibernate support unique constraint inside @TableGenerator
I tried generating the values for my primary keys using @tableGenerator annotation. Since this annotation will create a table and generate the value from it, I want to place a unique constraint on the ID value.
JPA documentation says we can use @uniqueConstraint inside @TableGenerator.
package org.example.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "student_id_generator")
    @TableGenerator(name = "student_id_generator",
                    table="id_generator",
                    pkColumnName = "SEQNAME",
                    pkColumnValue = "Student_Sequence",
                    valueColumnName = "ID_Value",
                    initialValue = 1,
                    allocationSize = 12,
                    uniqueConstraints = {
                        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"ID_Value"})
                    }
    )
    Long rollNumber;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}

@UniqueConstraint is placed on column ID_value but it is not working.
Why?
create table id_generator (
        ID_Value bigint,
        SEQNAME varchar(255) not null,
        primary key (SEQNAME)
    )


Currently, Hibernate both v6.5.3.Final and v6.6.1.Final seem that don't support this feature. In the application log is reported:
HHH000120: Ignoring unique constraints specified on table generator [student_id_generator]

Searching for this warning in the sources I reached to GenerationStrategyInterpreter class that contains the following:
// TODO : implement unique-constraint support
if ( tableGeneratorAnnotation.uniqueConstraints() != null
        && tableGeneratorAnnotation.uniqueConstraints().length > 0 ) {
    LOG.ignoringTableGeneratorConstraints( tableGeneratorAnnotation.name() );
}

Also, in Hibernate 7 (still in beta release), that constraints are read using the JPA @UniqueConstraint annotation in GeneratorParameters class but still not applied:
// TODO : implement unique-constraint support
final UniqueConstraint[] uniqueConstraints = tableGeneratorAnnotation.uniqueConstraints();
if ( CollectionHelper.isNotEmpty( uniqueConstraints ) ) {
    LOG.ignoringTableGeneratorConstraints( tableGeneratorAnnotation.name() );
}


Hi, Thank you so much for your detailed answer. So it is clear that it is not supported. Hope they would tell a reason why they are ignoring it.

I think it's time to open a feature request in https://discourse.hibernate.org/c/hibernate-orm/5 ;-)

Hi, I have never requested for a feature, but sure will try checking out the link you provided.
